# Objects of "Main.storyboard" dissapered when updated xcode 6.3.1

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I have this issue; when I UPDATED my XCode all the objects of the storyboard disappeared but all of them are declared and also when i run my app appear, but I can't them see in the storyboard.

I cant post the image but the icons (Image, button, backgroundImage) also are more clear than the others(Top Layout Guide, Bottom Layout Guide,..).

When I type this in the terminal appear this.

> MacBook-Pro-sadas:~ br$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
>
> objc[859]: Class IDEBlockScrollView is implemented in both
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/IDEKit
>   and
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEProductsUI.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEProductsUI.
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>
> 2015-06-22 11:28:46.396 Xcode[859:49829]  DeveloperPortal: Using
>   pre-existing current store at URL
>   (file:///Users/brbar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DeveloperPortal%206.3.1.db).
>
> 2015-06-22 11:33:38.567 Xcode[859:49800] Failed to connect
>   (comparisonSplitView) outlet from (DVTComparisonScrollCoordinator) to
>   (DVTComparisonSplitView): missing setter or instance variable
>
> 2015-06-22 11:33:38.581 Xcode[859:49800] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning
>   in
>   /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-7703/IDEKit/Editor/IDEEditorContext.m:2115
>
> Details:  Skipped applying state for Main.storyboard because it came
>   from a different document extension
>   (Xcode.IDEKit.InterfaceBuilder.EditorDocument.Storyboard vs
>   Xcode.IDEKit.EditorDocument.SourceCodeComparisonEditor)
>
> Object:

**Method:**   -_`applyEditorStateDictionary:forDocumentExtensionIdentifier:atDocumentURLToCurren`tEditor:

**Thread:**   `<NSThread: 0x7fc839e39200>{number = 1, name = main}`

Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.

Thanks for your time. Any opinion is welcome and sorry if this is so easy, I'm new on this and I have to start from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, its so weird but when I press "Show the version Editor" (icon with two opposed rows) the objects from the storyboard became invisible.

To fix this, I select every object and constrain that is invisible, then I clicked in the icon "Show the attributes inspector" and at the end there is a check box called "Installed". Just check it for each one and everything restore.